# Pipeline error (ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames)

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, pipeline

The example is fully reproducible. Here is full notebook (which downloads data too): https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/02_end_to_end_machine_learning_project.ipynb

After this part in notebook above:

```
full_pipeline_with_predictor = Pipeline([
        ("preparation", full_pipeline),
        ("linear", LinearRegression())
    ])

full_pipeline_with_predictor.fit(housing, housing_labels)
full_pipeline_with_predictor.predict(some_data)
```

I am trying to get predictions on the test set with this code:

```
X_test_prepared = full_pipeline.transform(X_test)
final_predictions = full_pipeline_with_predictor.predict(X_test_prepared)
```

But I am receiving error:

```
C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py:430: FutureWarning: Given feature/column names or counts do not match the ones for the data given during fit. This will fail from v0.24.
  FutureWarning)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Empty                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    796             try:
--> 797                 tasks = self._ready_batches.get(block=False)
    798             except queue.Empty:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\queue.py in get(self, block, timeout)
    166                 if not self._qsize():
--> 167                     raise Empty
    168             elif timeout is None:

Empty: 

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-141-dc87b1c9e658> in <module>
      5 
      6 X_test_prepared = full_pipeline.transform(X_test)
----> 7 final_predictions = full_pipeline_with_predictor.predict(X_test_prepared)
      8 
      9 final_mse = mean_squared_error(y_test, final_predictions)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py in <lambda>(*args, **kwargs)
    114 
    115         # lambda, but not partial, allows help() to work with update_wrapper
--> 116         out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)
    117         # update the docstring of the returned function
    118         update_wrapper(out, self.fn)

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in predict(self, X, **predict_params)
    417         Xt = X
    418         for _, name, transform in self._iter(with_final=False):
--> 419             Xt = transform.transform(Xt)
    420         return self.steps[-1][-1].predict(Xt, **predict_params)
    421 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in transform(self, X)
    586 
    587         self._validate_features(X.shape[1], X_feature_names)
--> 588         Xs = self._fit_transform(X, None, _transform_one, fitted=True)
    589         self._validate_output(Xs)
    590 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _fit_transform(self, X, y, func, fitted)
    455                     message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)))
    456                 for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(
--> 457                         self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True), 1))
    458         except ValueError as e:
    459             if "Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead" in str(e):

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
   1002             # remaining jobs.
   1003             self._iterating = False
-> 1004             if self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
   1005                 self._iterating = self._original_iterator is not None
   1006 

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
    806                 big_batch_size = batch_size * n_jobs
    807 
--> 808                 islice = list(itertools.islice(iterator, big_batch_size))
    809                 if len(islice) == 0:
    810                     return False

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    454                     message_clsname='ColumnTransformer',
    455                     message=self._log_message(name, idx, len(transformers)))
--> 456                 for idx, (name, trans, column, weight) in enumerate(
    457                         self._iter(fitted=fitted, replace_strings=True), 1))
    458         except ValueError as e:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _safe_indexing(X, indices, axis)
    404     if axis == 1 and indices_dtype == 'str' and not hasattr(X, 'loc'):
    405         raise ValueError(
--> 406             "Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for "
    407             "pandas DataFrames"
    408         )

ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

**Question:** How can I correct that error? And why that error happens?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since your final pipeline:

```
full_pipeline_with_predictor = Pipeline([
        ("preparation", full_pipeline),
        ("linear", LinearRegression())
    ])
```

clearly contains already the `full_pipeline`, you should not "prepare" again your `X_test`; doing so, you are "preparing" `X_test` twice, which is wrong. So, your code should be simply

```
final_predictions = full_pipeline_with_predictor.predict(X_test)
```

exactly as it is for getting predictions for `some_data`, i.e.

```
full_pipeline_with_predictor.predict(some_data)
```

which `some_data` you correctly do not "prepare" before feeding them into the final pipeline.

The whole point of using pipelines is exactly this, i.e. to avoid having to run separately fit-predict for possibly several preparation steps, having wrapped all of them into a single pipeline instead. You correctly apply this process here when you predict `some_data`, but you somehow seem to have forgotten it in the next step, when you try to predict `X_test`.